# Firebase Authentication Provider for a User changed automatically to E-Mail. How to change back?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In a Firebase project, I have activated multiple sign-in methods (e-mail, Google, and Microsoft), which all work fine. I also have it activated to only allow one account per e-mail address.

The problem arises when a user successfully signs in via Google or Microsoft, then signs out and then signs in via e-mail, using the same e-mail address as before using Google or Microsoft. Then his account type changes to e-Mail and it seems like a no way back.

Is there a way to change user account types from e-mail back to Microsoft or Google?

Comment: Is the user be able to sign in with Google after he signed in with email? If so, why do you concern? Also, when you use the admin SDK you should be able to retrieve ALL the sign-in providers for the same user (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#userrecord - and search for "provider_data")

Answer (score 0):

What you are writing in question seams not how it works. When you sign in using Google provider your email is verified automatly and if you try to sign in using same email authentication will throw error that account with that email allredy exists.

If you created first account using email and password and didn't verify your email addres then if you sign in using google provider with same email address in it, email and password provider will gone because of was not verified and you wont be able to login using email end password unless you will setup a new password for this email.

If email was verified and you sign in using google provider with same email address. This provider will be added to providers array and you will be able to login using email and password and google provider.

To add multiple providers to your accaunt you can use `linkWithPopup()` function. If you created accound with diferent email address and want to be able to log in on this account with provider who has diferent email address for example.

Comment: Well, that is my problem: User signs in using Microsoft. Firebase Console Authentication shows Account Type is Microsoft. User signs in using e-mail and uses the same e-mail address as the one in his Microsoft account. He gets in! And Firebase Console Authentication shows Account Type is E-Mail. It has changed! But why? I have disabled multiple providers for the same address? The sign-in attempt with type E-Mail with the same address as used in existing Microsoft account should have failed.

Comment: I never used microsoft provider only Gmail and always had error email already exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must have different functions written for different signin's. When the user first logs in, store his login method on firestore. You can get this from the signin function triggered or simply by the button user clicked. Then during each login add a check that if user exists and user's current signin method is not the same as the one stored on firestore, notify the user to use the correct one.

Or you can let the user signin using whatever they please but ultimately in your code, the function which is triggered will tell you the current signin method and you'd have the first/previous method stored. So you can do stuff accordingly.